# LiveData not notifying all items after adding one to database

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have a database in which I am storring some items from shopping list. I have two main activities - in one activity, I have a list of items with the state of  an item - (saved in shopping list or not). In another one - description of every item and button, which saves or removes items (based on condition). If I press a button, my list condition must change too, and it does not always works fine (I actually can not define where it works, and where does not). How do I fix this? My list class listens in observeForever `getAllShoppingListItemsIds()` to detect if an item was added or not.
Here is the code.

```
open class BaseViewModel(private val listDao: ShoppingListDao) : BaseViewModel() {
    protected fun addItemToShoppingList(sku: Sku) {
        doAsync {
            listDao.addItemToShoppingList(SavedShoppingListModel(sku.code, sku.title, sku.subTitle, sku.description, sku.image, sku.validityStartDate, sku.validityEndDate, sku.offerDescription, sku.regularPrice.toString(), sku.discountPrice.toString(), Const.SHOPPING_LIST_CATALOG, 1, Date(), false))
        }
    }

    protected fun addItemToShoppingList(savedItem: SavedShoppingListModel) {
        doAsync {
            listDao.addItemToShoppingList(savedItem)
        }
    }

    protected fun removeItemFromShoppingList(id: String) {
        doAsync {
            listDao.deleteById(id)
        }
    }

    protected fun getAllShoppingListItemsIds() = listDao.getAllShoppingListItemsIds()

    protected fun getShoppingListItemBydId(id: String) = listDao.getShoppingListItemBydId(id)

    protected fun getShoppingListItemUidBydId(id: String) = listDao.getShoppingListItemUidBydId(id)
}
```

Comment: perhaps the values you insert are updating.. can you pass the code of your DAO ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in `observeForever` in BaseViewModel. If you will move observation from your viewModel in Activity or Fragment with `observe` (not `observeForever`), all notifications will work